# How to avoid image flicker in IE using timer

Tags: image, internet-explorer, flickr

I have the following code which causes smooth playback in Chrome.  but in IE10 it causes a flicker.  Are there workarounds at all?

Thanks

HTML

```
<a href="#" title="Play Motion Clip from Beginning">
<img alt="Play Motion" src="../Images/play_green_controls.png" style="border-style: none; width: 32px; height: 32px; background-color: #000000; cursor: pointer;"
            id="btnPlay" />
</a>
<div id="divImage" >
hello andy
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cache = [];
    var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
    var interval = 100;
    var _total = 0;

    $("#btnPlay").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default3.aspx/GetClips",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                cache = [];
                 _total = 0;
                $.each(msg.d, function () {
                    var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
                    cacheImage.src = this['Text'];
                    cache[_total] = cacheImage;
                    _total++;
                }
                );
                setInterval('swapImages()', interval);
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            }
        });
    });
    var div = document.getElementById('divImage');
    var _index = 0;
    function swapImages() {

        if (_index < _total) {              
            if (_index > 0) {
                div.removeChild(cache[_index - 1]);
            }               
            div.appendChild(cache[_index]);
        }
        else {
            interval = 0;
        }
        _index++;
        if (_index  == _total)
        {
            div.removeChild(cache[_index - 1]);
            _index = 0;
            div.appendChild(cache[_index]);
        }
    }

Code Behind:

    [WebMethod]
    public static ArrayList GetClips()
    {
        ArrayList _arr = new ArrayList();
        int _max = 250;  //seems to be safe
        string[] _files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Cloud\Catalogues\000EC902F17F\2\2013\10\6\10\f1fe61da-4684-48ed-a503-4a5586ece9c8","*.jpg"); //731
           for (int _index = 0; _index < _files.Length; _index++)
        {
            string _file = _files[_index];
            string[] _bits = _file.Split('\\');
            string _url = "Portal/Catalogues/000EC902F17F/2/2013/10/6/10/f1fe61da-4684-48ed-a503-4a5586ece9c8/" + _bits[10];
            ListItem _item = new ListItem();
            _item.Text = _url;
            _arr.Add(_item);
            if (_index == _max - 1)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return _arr;
    }
```